# How to change the Unicode for an ::after object in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, unicode

How to change the Unicode for an ::after object in wordpress?
I tried to do it in css and it just imputed the unicode code instead of the icon?

The original code is this:

```
.x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li>a>span:after {
    content: "\f103";
    margin-left: 0.35em;
    font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

And the code I updated it to is this. I have tried using an !important; tag on the end of the unicode line and no luck, so I took that out...

```
x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li>a>span:after {
    content: "f0d7";
    margin-left: 0.35em;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: rgba(82, 76, 76, 0.43);
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

This is my div site below.

http://wvleadership.cyndeeadkins.com/

So what am I doing wrong and why is this so hard to over ride?

Comment: I noticed in my code on the site I have content: "\f0d7";
but when it renders online it renders the code as content: "f0d7"; ?? Why does it do that?

Comment: `"f0d7"` is not the same as `"\f0d7"`...This could be a caching issue. I'm not sure where / how you're changing it, so it could be that something is stripping out the backslash...

Comment: @rnevius, yes I know they are not the same. I added the \ in my code but, like you said, something is stripping it out. Any idea what could do that?

Comment: @mevius, just an update. By putting it into the "customizer" in the wordpress theme, it actually strips out the "\". They suggested either adding "\\" so that one would stay, or forgoing the customizer all together and adding it into the childetheme file. I opted to just put it in the childtheme and it worked fine. It didn't strip anything out.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found out why it was dropping the "\" from the code. I finally got a response from the wordpress theme developer. This will be nice to know for anyone else dealing with an issue like above.

There were two issues all together. 
 #1 issue: I was saving this css code in the custom css section within the 
"customizer" and it apparently doesn't like that. You need to save it in the child-theme's style.css file instead.

## 2 issue: I needed to add a little more code to the string, adding "body" in the beginning.

```
body .x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li>a>span:after {
content: "\f0ab";
```

}

I updated the child theme css file, then refreshed the caching and it worked. :D